# Performing multiple queries and joining the result tables of those queries all on the mongodb server side before returning to client APP

Tags: mongodb, nosql, query-optimization

In my database there are severy collections.

I need to perform a query on each of those collections.

And then join the output of those queries by a common id field.

As far as I know, I need to perform several queries and then join the outputs when the results are returned to the client.

Can this be done with one query call to MongoDB?

EDITED:

each of those collections will be sharded.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect you want through the [Aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-stages) feature of MongoDB.

- Use [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#-lookup--aggregation-) to query on multiple collections.
- Use [`$unwind`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#-unwind--aggregation-) to make field key.
- Use [`$project`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#-project--aggregation-) to make your own output.

#### For example:

- Script:

```
db.mainusers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'subusers',
      localField: 'name',
      foreignField: 'name',
      as: 'subusers',
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$subusers',
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      email: 1,
      name: 1,
      subuserInfo: '$subusers.info',
    },
  },
])
```

- Result:

```js
{
  _id: 'U5967278ce90299ce10f545889b786ba7',
  email: 'xxxx@xxxx.com',
  name: 'Jay',
  subuserInfo: 'Some subuser Info',
}
```

Comment: Will it work with sharded collections?

Comment: Check this document from MongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/#aggregation-pipeline-and-sharded-collections