# Optimizing query that makes 3 API calls to the MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql, aggregation-framework, query-optimization

```js
const user_schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    collection: `user`,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


const test_schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    test_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    collection: `test`,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const score_schema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "user",
      required: true,
    },
    test_id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "test",
      required: true,
    },
    test_score: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    collection: `score`,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

query:

Given an array of user_id and an array of test_id, query the `score` model to find out the test scores.
To get the array of `user_id`, a set of conditions is given and the `user` model must be queried to find the set of users matching the conditions.
To get the array of `test_id`, a set of conditions is given and the `test` model must be queried to find the set of tests matching the conditions.

What needs to be done:

1. Make one query request to the MongoDB server to get the array of `user_id`.
2. Make a separate query request to the MongoDB server to get the array of `test_id`.
3. Make another query request to the MongoDB server to get the test scores:

```js
db.getCollection("score").aggregate([
  {$match: {$and: {user_id: {$in: array_of_user_id}, {test_id: {$in: array_of_test_id}}}}}
])
```

Is this the most optimal way to get the test scores? Is it possible to make just one request to the MongoDB server?

Comment: try [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: @YuTing could you write an answer involving $lookup? thanks

Comment: Give some valid testing data of all three collections instead of giving schema.

Comment: Consider to put `test` and `test` data in `score` collection as embedded elements.

Comment: You are asking more or less the same question  again and again. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71610845/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71610822/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71608189/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71603633/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71596579/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71596502/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71595413/3027266, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71594071/3027266 Maybe you should finally describe your actual problem. Provide some realistic sample data. Tell us what does not work as you would expect. What did you try so far?